# выбрать значение до ?clear_cache=Y

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть `url` со следующим адресом `site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory?clear_cache=Y`.

Мне нужно получить

```
site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory/grazhdanskie-spory
```

Пробую

```
$url = preg_replace("#^/content/([a-zA-Z-])+#",$1","site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory?clear_cache=Y");
```

но выводится не то, как поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучшее решение, в вашем случае - это решение Дмитрия, но вы также можете использовать для подобных целей встроенную функцию parse_url, которая разбирает URL по частям и помещает результаты в массив.

```
$link = 'http://site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory?clear_cache=Y';
if ($url = parse_url($link)) {
 printf('%s://%s%s', $url['scheme'], $url['host'], $url['path']);
}
```

Ниже вы задали вопрос, что Вы хотите получить конечную точку пути в URL.

Предлагаю 2 варианта решения данной задачи:

**1: parse_url**

```
$url = 'http://site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory?clear_cache=Y';
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $url_path);
$last = end($parts);
echo $last;
```

**2: basename**

```
$url = "http://site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory?clear_cache=Y";
$lastPath = preg_replace("/\?.*/", "", basename($url));
```

basename вернет конечную точку пути в URL, но она будет равна: grazhdanskie-spory?clear_cache=Y в данном случае, поэтому ее нужно обрезать с помощью регулярного выражения.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как получить такое решение, допустим есть такая ссылка site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory/text1/....../textN?clear_cache=Y Как получить значение textN? Ну т .е не важно какой длинны будет ссылка, главное получить значение между ? и последним /

Comment: Обновил ответ :)

Answer (score 2):

Это то, что нужно

```
preg_replace("/\?.*/", "$1/grazhdanskie-spory", "site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory?clear_cache=Y");

// site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory/grazhdanskie-spory
```

Comment: Поменяйте второй параметр "$1/grazhdanskie-spory" на '', тогда конструкция станет универсальной и поможет обрезать любые параметры запроса, а также не будет еще раз добавлять "grazhdanskie-spory", который по сути не нужен)

Comment: Думаю, ответ должен быть [`preg_replace("/\?.*/", "/grazhdanskie-spory", "site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory?clear_cache=Y");`](http://ideone.com/5VGsmd). В шаблоне нет захватывающих подмасок, поэтому `$1` не нужен.

Comment: Wiktor, тут в целом второй параметр должен быть пустой, вывод вашей функции site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory/grazhdanskie-spory, дублирование grazhdanskie-spory я думаю не требуется.

Comment: @Firepro: *Мне нужно получить `site.ru/content/grazhdanskie-spory/grazhdanskie-spory`*